# Getting Undefined property when trying to access Delphi Array from a SOAP service

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, delphi, soap

As the title suggests. I inherited a SOAP based web app at my job and I want to setup some parsing gimmicks so I can see what it's doing (It's a SQL request generator basically)

Here is the class/object I am getting returned while calling a certain function via PHP through my SOAP service.

```
  ProductAvailabilityResult = Class(TRemotable)
  private
    FProductAvailableList : ProductAvailabilityList;
    FResultArray : TArray<string>;
  published
    //@PROPERTY@ProductAvailableList:ProductAvailabilityList
    //@PROPERTYDESC@List of products and their availibility
    property ProductAvailableList : ProductAvailabilityList read FProductAvailableList write FProductAvailableList;
    property ResultArray : TArray<string> read FResultArray write FResultArray;

  End;
```

The **ProductAvailableList** is an array of an object, which that object itself contains multiple properties. This particular array works.

However my array **ResultArray** does not work and keeps throwing me a **Undefined property: stdClass::$ResultArray**.

This is how i'm assigning values to the array.

```
  SetLength(ArrayTest,conditionList.Count);
  for I := 0 to conditionlist.Count - 1 do
  begin
      ArrayTest[I] := conditionList[I];
  end;
  aProductAvailabilityResult.ResultArray := ArrayTest;
```

The **conditionList** is a TStringList i'm dumping into my array which I then try to echo the first item in a PHP file i'm using to call the function. The first echo is my array, which returns my error. The second is a for loop done in the other array that works fine.

```
    echo $result->ResultArray[0];

    foreach (($result->ProductAvailableList) as $aProd)
    {
            echo "PRODUCTID:            $aProd->Productid".'<br>';
            echo "-ProductCode:             $aProd->ProductCode".'<br>';
            echo "-Quantity Available:      $aProd->Available".'<br>';
            echo "-Retail Price:            $$aProd->RetailPrice".'<br>';
            echo "-SKU detail:".'<br>';
            // For each product, we list the SKU and its availability
            foreach (($aProd->SkuAvailableList) as $aSku)
            {
                    echo "--SKUID: $aSku->Skuid / Quantity Available: $aSku->Available".'<br>';             
            }
```

EDIT: Just found an extra bit of relevant information. Looking at the WSDL definitions on the client, my Array does not appear there. As you can see in the screenshot, I need my array to be there to even access it (there's more there than in my class because I edited that out to shorten this post). Why is WSDL not picking up the property?

EDIT2: The below is now populated with the field I added, seems it was just not refreshing the WSDL page properly. However, I still get the same error. Where am I supposed to define the property then? This is driving me insane...

[image]

Comment: This is what I meant last time about the remoting being the critical point of this

Comment: Delphi has issues with published and generics. Try using TStringDynArray for FResultArray type.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Didn't work, I still cannot see the property in the WSDL definitions...